# Bootstrap.js Object Expected IE

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have been working with adding bootstrap to my website to utilize its versatility so i downloaded the files from [www.getbootstrap.com](http://www.getbootstrap.com), however, when using Internet Explorer in debug mode, I consistently get the error 'Object Expected' (see images below). I have not changed anything in the bootstrap code.

The files work and its awesome to be able to utilize the preset capabilities, but I get the error every time I have a post-back or load the page. I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox and it works without a hitch but when using IE it says there is an error every page load and post-back, but once past that error the page works fine. I'm no expert by any stretch of the imagination in Javascript (hence why i downloaded the preset capabilities of bootstrap!)

Please let me know if you need me to post a revision to the question or if there is a better way of doing things.

Thanks in Advance!

```
$(function () {

    $.support.transition = (function () {

      var transitionEnd = (function () {

        var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')
          , transEndEventNames = {
               'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd'
            ,  'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend'
            ,  'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend'
            ,  'transition'       : 'transitionend'
            }
          , name

        for (name in transEndEventNames){
          if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
            return transEndEventNames[name]
          }
        }

      }())

      return transitionEnd && {
        end: transitionEnd
      }

    })()

})
```

[Code Error In IE Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Fac.png)

[Proof of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fYGs.png)

Comment: Please show the HTML that's including jQuery and Bootstrap into your page. It could be jQuery isn't loading before Bootstrap.js.

Comment: do i need to load the jQuery first?

Comment: Yes, see this example: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: That Worked!! thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure jQuery is loaded before bootstrap.js. From [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/):

> note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files)

From the [example template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template):

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```